# Saving and restoring queries in flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, serialization, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building queries based on searches done by the user, but only extracting slices. Within the next 10 minutes, the user may request the next slice\page, so I'd like to store the query and restore it IF the user wants the next slice. Ideally I'd prefer not to construct the query from scratch but to restore it to the state that it was, but then grab the next slice.

I've come across --> http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/serializer.html which seems to be targeted at this use case, however when I attempt to run it on my queries I run into issues.

> lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
>       raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.**name**
>   TypeError: can't pickle function objects

My suspicion is that it is due to flask-SQLAlchemy using functions within the query object however I'm not sure exactly where the issue is.

Do you have tips or suggestions on how to move forward with this? Or maybe an alternative approach.

This is the code that appears to break it.

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.serializer import loads, dumps
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Blink(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uploaded_sd = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    blink_metadata = relationship("BlinkMetadata", remote_side='BlinkMetadata.blink_id',
                                  primaryjoin='blink.c.id==blink_metadata.c.blink_id')


class BlinkMetadata(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    blink_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('blink.id'), index=True)
    metadata_id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    metadata_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    blink = relationship("Blink", remote_side='Blink.id',
                         primaryjoin=('blink_metadata.c.blink_id==blink.c.id'))

def make_sample_query():
    q = db.session.query(Blink).filter(Blink.uploaded_sd == 1)

    activity_filter = (
        (BlinkMetadata.metadata_id == 1) &
        (BlinkMetadata.metadata_type_id == 1)
    )

    q = q.join(Blink.blink_metadata, aliased=True).filter(activity_filter)

    serialised_query = dumps(q)
```

Comment: some bugs have been fixed in serializer, so I'd recommend trying the most recent version just to make sure that issue persists.  but yeah, it's very difficult to pickle a Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this, I've taken different tact. Instead, I build up the query as a string (as a ORM string, not a SQL string). I'm then storing the query, and restoring and executing it as needed using **eval()**.

I pass the query string to **page_query()**, then call pages as needed using **next_page()**.

```
def page_query(query_string):

  transaction_id = create_query_transaction(0, BLINKS_PAGE_SIZE, query_string)
  return transaction_id


def next_page(transaction_id):

    transaction = BlinkQueryTransaction.query.get(transaction_id)

    query = eval(transaction.sql)
    query = query.slice(transaction.latest_offset, transaction.page_size)

    transaction.latest_offset = transaction.latest_offset + transaction.page_size
    db.session.commit()

    return query


def create_query_transaction(latest_offset, page_size, query):

    bqt = BlinkQueryTransaction(latest_offset=latest_offset, page_size=page_size, sql=query)
    bqt = save_to_db(bqt)

    return bqt.id
```